# ADO.NET Entity Model Update

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, entities

Hi i am trying to update a record from the database, but for some reason the record is not updated. I am using ADO.NET entity Framework 4.0

```
public void updateCredits(string username)
 {
     myDBEntities Entity = new myDBEntities();
     User u = Entity.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.username == username)
     u.firstname = "name";
     u.credits = 11.5;
     Entity.SaveChanges();
 }
```

I tried restarting VS and even the SQL Server but no luck. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What's the type of `u.credits`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code -- there's obviously more to this issue than the actual code you've displayed.

Comment: Sure change tracking is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an issue with change tracking.  You can try manually marking the `User` entity as changed like so:

```
public void updateCredits(string username)
 {
     myDBEntities Entity = new myDBEntities();
     User u = Entity.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.username == username)
     u.firstname = "name";
     u.credits = 11.5;
     Entity.Entry(u).State = EntityState.Modified;  //<-- manually indicate the entity was changed
     Entity.SaveChanges();
 }
```

If the above code works, then there's a good chance ChangeTracking is being disabled somehow.

Comment: thank you brian for your fast reply. I managed to solve the problem by removing all the tables from the ADO.NET Entity and adding them again. :) Thanks